# Exiting and Restarting a Function in Lua

Tags: function, lua

My problem is that I have a `function a()` that I need to exit unconditionally at certain times. My question is how would I achieve the goal of exiting a function without conditions.

```
Example:

 local function a()
   --Do Stuff
 end

 a()
```

Another words, is there a way to exit `a()` with a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
function a()
    -- do stuff
    if time_to_exit then
        return 
    end
    -- do more stuff
end
```

The `time_to_exit` can be anything you want: check if something has become true or non-nil or check that time has elapsed, etc. The details really depend on what you want to achieve (if you need more detail, clarify your post and post a comment to this answer so I know).

Answer (score 6):

There are only few ways to "exit" a function: `return`, `coroutine.yield` (if the function is executed as a coroutine), and `error()` call (which you can trap with `pcall` around the function).

I'm not sure what you mean by "exiting a function without conditions", but one of these options should work for you as there is nothing else available. (You can also use debug hook and call `error()` from it without modifying your function code at all, but I would not expect this to be needed in your case.)

Answer (score 1):

`do return end` placed anywhere in a function will unconditionally exit the function when reached.

```
function a()
    -- some stuff
    do return end
    -- some more stuff (that won't execute)
end
```